# Alexa: Call upon built-in intent

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing a custom skill, where I want to be able to call upon another intent, as I want to be able to say 'TestSkill, what is happening here today?' and then call upon 'AMAZON.SearchAction' for todays calendar, but haven't been able to figure out how to do this.

```
'calendarIntent' : function() {
    this.emit('AMAZON.SearchAction<object@Calendar>');
}
```

So what do I need to do to invoke the built-in search-action? So one can access the calendar without mentioning it?